# using TextEdit on Mac...doesn't display as a web page. advice?

Tags: html

I save a basic "Hello World" html file on TextEdit on my mac, but it won't open as a webpage and I just see code when I open the file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Go to your text edit and under prefrences
```

[image]

```
Make sure this is checked
```

[image]

```
Make sure plain text is selected
```

[image]

```
Create a new file and named the file with format also

For example: index.html            <--- where html is the format

Then you are good to go!
```

[image]